# Listener on text within JLabel

Tags: java, swing

I'm building a program in Java, using `Swing`, that will act as an interactive presentation.

I have paragraphs I need to display (presumably in `JLabel`s) , and within each paragraph are certain words and phrases that need to be formatted differently (have a different color), and I need them to call a method that will display something else when clicked or hovered over.

I know there must be a way to accomplish this...

Comment: html format is applicable for JLabel..

Comment: @subash yeah, I know I can hyperlink using html but how can I call a method in my program with html?

Comment: trying to get a text to listen !! sounds little less sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply some style, you can use HTML in your `JLabel`'s content.

If you need some custom behavior and you want to handle it in a different way for some parts of your `JLabel`, you need your component to be split in a more detailed way. 
Create a container(`JPanel`) and arrange you components within it. From now, your smaller components will be able to listen for events like `mouseEntered` and `mouseClicked` and handle them separately, not confusing the whole `JLabel` component.

In this way, every **smart** part of text will be a standalone component.